# How to set spinnerMode in Android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Can I use `android:spinnerMode` xml attribute in Android 2.2?

I need to get an inline dropdown anchored to the `Spinner` widget than getting in dialog window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jake Wharton, the author of `ActionBarSherlock` library, made possible to use `IcsSpinner` outside of action bar. Read through this discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/actionbarsherlock/fL-JL6Mn7kg/discussion

`IcsSpinner` allow to setup `dropdown` or `dialog` mode.