# How to set the spinner mode dynamically?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have created a `Spinner` dynamically, which is easy with `new Spinner(context)`.
But now I need to set the `spinnerMode` dynamically, and I find no method to do so.

What should I do?

Comment: What is a "spinner mode"?

Comment: [spinnerMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:spinnerMode)

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: I don't have any...I was just explaining what a `spinnerMode` is to everyone. I haven't found anything in the docs showing it can be done in java. You could set up different `Themes` and change the `Themes` but this has to be done before `setContentView()` is called

Answer (score 4):

in android >= 3.0 (API 11) you can use this :

```
    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this,null,android.R.style.Widget_Spinner,Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);
```

Answer (score -1):

OK you can try with..

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourArrayAdapter);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Or,

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, yourArrayAdapter);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Also you can see..

- [How to set spinnerMode in Android 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840636/how-to-set-spinnermode-in-android-2-2)

Comment: "i need to set the spinner mode dynamically. " this isn't dynamically

Comment: using different layout has nothing to do with setting spinner mode